# SwiftUI macOS Running a function to set a menu item to enabled?

Tags: xcode, macos, swiftui, menuitem

I'm trying to find out how to set a specific Main Menu item on SwiftUI macOS to be selected, after it has been run.

AppDelegate.swift

```
    @IBAction func duckduckgo(_ sender: Any) {
        let contentView = ContentViewDemo()
        window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        window.center()
        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
        window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        window.title = "DuckDuckGo http://duckduckgo.com"
        self.browser.load(url: URL(string: "http://duckduckgo.com")!)
NSMenuItem (duckduckgo isEnabled: true)
    }
```

I see that a NSMenuItem can be set to isEnabled:true - but I'm not entirely sure why adding it  (like the above) does not do anything.

Thing is, the rest of the items in the menu should also be set to off when that one is set to On. Is that possible?

Comment: You need to use `validateUserIterfaceItem` or `validateMenuItem`, [here is Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UIValidation/UIValidation.html?language=objc#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000040i) of how to do that.